# Referencing a private module global variable in a class method

Tags: python

I recently stumbled on a strange behavior of Python, related to module variables and their use in a class' method of that same module, and I couldn't find any information, so I'm turning to StackOverflow :)

Here is a small python script that you can run directly, it shows my problem :

```
__foo = "private foo"
foo = "public foo"

class Test:

    def test(self):
        self.test_public()
        self.test_private()

    def test_private(self):
        global __foo
        print("{0}".format(__foo))

    def test_public(self):
        global foo
        print("{0}".format(foo))

test = Test()
test.test()
```

Strangely enough, this simple test will fail on the `test_private` call. The output of this script is the following :

```
public foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    test.test()
  File "test.py", line 9, in test
    self.test_private()
  File "test.py", line 13, in test_private
    print("{0}".format(__foo))
NameError: global name '_Test__foo' is not defined
```

As you can see, this works fine with the `foo` variable, but the `__foo` one's name gets mangled with the name of the class, resulting in a crash.

I couldn't find any mention of this behaviour in the Python documentation, and I was wondering if this is intended, or if I'm doing something wrong ?

And in any cases, is there any way of working around this limitation ? In my use case, I replaced my private variable by a public one, but I'd really like to make it private again ...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I know that there is no reall private methods / variables in Python, this is a figure of speach. The double underscore is the convention used where I work, so I need to stick with it as much as possible.

Comment: Check out the "private name mangling" section on [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=mangling#atom-identifiers) page. "When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, [...] the transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. "

Comment: `print(globals()['__foo'])` is one way to get at it.  But *really* just mark your "private" variables with a single underscore, the convention is strong enough.

Comment: Python doesn't have *private variables* - `__foo` is accessible from outside the script.

Comment: Ok, I thought that explicitely adding the `global` keyword would tell the Python interpreter that the variable doesn't belong to the class scope. I think I'll go with the `globals()["__foo"]` method then.

Thanks for the comment/answer !

Comment: @Citron I would recommend against that; use a single underscore instead. You aren't preventing access to the variable, but are making your code harder to read.

Comment: @johnrsharpe : see the edit to my original question. I need to stick to double underscore, or no underscores at all. As for the code being harder to read, in my real case, I can easilly work around this.